# str does not support the buffer interface using .find

Tags: python-3.x

trying to search within a `.thumbdata3` file for `thumbnail` images. This was someone else's sample code, but I am getting an error

> "str does not support the buffer interface using .find"

```
"""extract files from Android thumbdata3 file"""

f=open('thumbdata3.dat','rb')
tdata = f.read()
f.close()

ss = '\xff\xd8'
se = '\xff\xd9'

count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
    if x1 < 0:
    break
    x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
    jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
    count += 1
    fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
    fw = open(fname,'wb')
    fw.write(jpg)
    fw.close()
    start = x2+2
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, turned out to be very simple.

just add b in front of the data I am trying to match

so

```
ss = '\xff\xd8'
se = '\xff\xd9'
```

becomes

```
ss = b'\xff\xd8'
se = b'\xff\xd9'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all right.
With Python 3.x like python-3.6.2

Rename .thumbdata3-1763508120 file to thumbdata3.dat

Rename .thumbdata3--1967290299 file to thumbdata4.dat

```
enter code here
"""extract files from Android thumbdata3 file"""
f=open('thumbdata3.dat','rb')
tdata = f.read()
f.close()

ss = b'\xff\xd8'
se = b'\xff\xd9'

count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
    if x1 < 0:
        break
    x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
    jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
    count += 1
    fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
    fw = open(fname,'wb')
    fw.write(jpg)
    fw.close()
    start = x2+2



enter code here
"""extract files from Android thumbdata4 file"""
f=open('thumbdata4.dat','rb')
tdata = f.read()
f.close()

ss = b'\xff\xd8'
se = b'\xff\xd9'

count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
    if x1 < 0:
        break
    x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
    jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
    count += 1
    fname = 'extracted%d04.jpg' % (count)
    fw = open(fname,'wb')
    fw.write(jpg)
    fw.close()
    start = x2+2
```